# Single word for a person who hates their birthday

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a person who hates their own birthday?

Comment: Where in the question did I mention that I need one badly? It is just out of curiosity.

Comment: ..... _over-21_

Comment: ... unpresentable

Comment: This will not answer your question in full , but anyway - check this:
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fragapane%20phobia

Comment: @Rossitten Thanks. I think if there is no one word for what I am looking for, I can use this definition. Please post your comment as answer

Comment: Evol, I wonder why you'd need a single word so badly because a few words are just as good or better, and I don't see why a single word would be useful at all if you're just curious if one exists. Therefore, I infer that you must need it badly. Like the Joker is threatening your family unless you come up with one.

Comment: I think "old" comes pretty close.  (Though, oddly, even fairly young people tend to hate their birthday if it falls on Christmas.)

Comment: _self-birthday-hater_

Comment: No reason to downvote this question, here's at least one +1 to try to correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have  a look at Urban Dictionary's entry:

[fragapane phobia](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fragapane%20phobia)

Probably not exactly what you are looking for but at least it is something =)
Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I can use this instead. Thanks a lot @Rossitten. But I didn't get why I get so many down votes. If there is no word for it then the simple answer to the question would be NO. Thanks anyways, this is helpful.